# How to store a unique filepath in database, too long for unique key

Tags: mysql, unix

I have a volume where I need to store the filepaths in a database. However, the filepaths are longer than the max length for a mysql index, so I'm not sure how I can store them and ensure uniqueness. An example path would be:

```
/Volume/00_ARCHIVE/Discovery/Alaska_The_Last_Frontier/2014-01-01/Alaska_The_Last_Frontier/DISC00000000927664/DISC00000000927664.mp4
```

How could I store this in mysql and ensure uniqueness on the path? The reason I need to do this is to see which paths have been removed (by doing a set diff), which paths are already there ( by doing a union) and which paths are new. How could I store this?

My first thought is to save an md5 checksum of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hash it. MD5 or SHA1 is just fine, since you don't have to worry about security here.

Comment: This seems the simplest solution. I mean, technically two of the files paths [could have the same MD5](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/), but it's not likely. You're also looking for string uniqueness which is a bit slow in million+ row tables. But, the quickest solution likely. Do MD5 and just store the actual plaintext path in a different column for reference.